# How to zoom the image view within collection view effectively

Tags: ios

1. I’m trying to Zoom the image view in a collection view with a help of a scroll view. But as I couldn't get any resources (though I did go through the recent Ray Wenderlich UIScrollView Tutorial for zooming image view) for zooming any view in a collection view, so I did it by changing the constraints of the image view and setting the minimum zoom scale of the scroll view (as the image size can be smaller or larger).

   My problem is that I can't restrict the image trying to zoom (In and Out) and therefore trying to change its constraints initially when the cell deques (biz of setting zoom scale in layout subviews) which looks very odd.

   [image: Image zooming initially]
2. In the same section, I don't want to centre the image view every time in `scrollViewDidZoom` method because it's not smooth, but I want to centre the image view immediately after the cell deques. For that I should call the `changeConstraints` method in `layoutSubviews`
   method or in `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method from the view controller by accessing the cell (I have one more problem here it won't give cell in viewDidLayoutSubviews sometimes). But in these methods the image view doesn't align properly at the centre.

   That's because in `layoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` I'm not able to get the proper image view size right after the scroll view ends zooming. So `frame.size.width - condoImageView.frame.size.width` will not cancel out
   and it will give some x offset which shouldn't be happening initially.

### Code

My layout subviews code goes here

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    minimumZoomScale = getTheInitialZoomScale()
    maximumZoomScale = minimumZoomScale * kMaximumZoomScaleMultiplier
    scrollView.zoomScale = minimumZoomScale
    changeConstraints()
}
```

Scroll view delegate methods goes here

```
func scrollViewDidZoom(scrollView: UIScrollView)  {
    changeConstraints()
}
func scrollViewDidEndZooming(scrollView: UIScrollView, withView view: UIView?, atScale scale: CGFloat) {
    changeConstraints()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    changeConstraints()
}
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    changeConstraints()
}

func scrollViewDidEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if !decelerate {
        changeConstraints()
    }
}

func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}
func changeConstraints() {

    let yOffset = max(0, (frame.size.height - condoImageView.frame.size.height) / 2)
    imageViewTopConstriant.constant = yOffset
    imageViewBottomConstriant.constant = yOffset

    let xOffset = max(0, (frame.size.width - condoImageView.frame.size.width) / 2)
    imageViewLeadingConstriant.constant = xOffset
    imageViewTrailingConstriant.constant = xOffset

    self.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

View did layout subviews code in view controller

```
 override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forItem: selectedImageIndex, inSection: 0)) as? CollectionViewCell
    cell?.changeConstraints()
}
```

### Screen shot

[image: Image not centring properly]

That forces me to call the `changeConstraints` method in `scrollViewDidZoom`.

So please can someone suggest me what to do to work this zooming effectively?