# How to centre the image view within a collection view cell after zooming?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, zooming

I have a collection view in which i have set of images to be displayed.

Im trying to zoom the image view inside a collection view with the help of a scroll view. But when i zoom a black patch is visible if i pan to the bottom or top of the scroll view after zooming. I don't know how to eliminate the black patch.

The black patch is visible because my image view is having width and height same as the scroll view and the content mode is aspect fit so that even the portrait image should be fit within the cell.

[image]

I have my scroll view as subview of the cell and image view as subview of the scrollView My scroll view and its constraints goes here

[image]
[image]

The screen shot after zooming and panning to the Bottom of the scroll view the red highlighted area shows the black patch.
[image]

I have posted a question on stack overflow recently in which i tried to solve this but i got some problems with that too [How to zoom the image view within collection view effectively??](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36306936/how-to-zoom-the-image-view-within-collection-view-effectively)